# Does album start with a vowel or consonant

Tags: grammar, american-english, pronunciation

"Album"? Does it start with a vowel sound or consonant?

Comment: It starts with a vowel sound:  "an album".

Answer (score 1):

It starts with a vowel sound.

Pronunciation > ˈ**a**lbəm